# Android DDMS incoming call does not seem to work on AVD with Google API level 11

Tags: android, ddms, phone-call, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have successfully used incoming calls using DDMS on AVD's with level 8 Google API, but when I try the same with an AVD with level 11 Google API, nothing happens.

Has anybody got this to work on any AVD running level 11 API, Google or "plain"?

Answer (score 1):

There are no phones running API Level 11, and therefore the emulator probably does not emulate a phone.